# Codeigniter active record get records from mysql where ids equal those in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I have an array that includes the following data:

```
array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["project_id"]=> string(2) "14" } [1]=> array(1) { ["project_id"]=> string(2) "21" } [2]=> array(1) { ["project_id"]=> string(2) "13" } }
```

I need to echo return all rows from my database where the project ids are equal to the ones in my array.

Using the below code how can I only get the records where the ids equal those in the database???

```
    function get_projects($id){
        $data = '';

        $this->db->where('id', $id); //HOW TO GET MULTIPLE IDS
        $query = $this->db->get('projects'); 

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'user_id' => $row->user_id,
                'project_name' => $row->project_name,
            );
        }

        return $data;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `where_in();`

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_in('username', $names);
// Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

See [the user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) for more.

Comment: How can I get the data out of the multidimensional array and into a standard array like in your answer???

Comment: A simple foreach loop should make it easy to get the values from the multi-dimensional array and put it into a flat array.

Comment: Can you help me to do it or should I open a new question, have searched but cannot find the answer to suit my needs...

Comment: I'm in and out of here today so I would recommend asking a new question. Make sure you show some code your tried in your question or else you'll get voted down. That happens a lot with looping questions. They like to see an effort first before offering help. And if you do post a new question post the link here so I can find it and try to get to it if i can.